# Is there a way to combine two columns in a dataset, keeping the larger float64 using Pandas?

Tags: dataframe, merge, nan, pandas

Ill try to keep it simple, but these are very large datasets I am working with.
Theoretically I am trying to combine Columns A and B of my data frame.
But, if A has a value in a row then B doesn't, and vice versa. That hole is filled with 'NaN'

A {1,2,NaN,4,5}
B {NaN,NaN,3,NaN,NaN}

I need A to equal {1,2,3,4,5}

EDIT:

Using
df.rename(columns{"a":"b"})
before you concatenate your data allows them to be combined easily is the only layering values layer over NaN.

Comment: what have you tried? what did not work as expected?

Comment: Hey, I have tried pd.combine, pd.combine_first, and pd.concat.

Comment: I created a model and two of the datasets use different columns names to represent the same information so when I combined them It left blanks in each respective columns where the data, fit together like puzzle pieces.

Comment: Ah, just thought of an idea, perhaps I can rename the columns that are labeled differently to have the same name so when I concatenate them they maintain flush. Ill try and if it works I'll probably take this down.

Comment: Yeah df.rename(column{" ": " "}) before concatenating worked.

Comment: please, add all that info your Question to make it useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['A'] = df['A'].fillna(df['B'])
```

What this code does is fill all missing values of column `A` with the values found in column `B`.

For more options see: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17769/how-to-fill-missing-value-based-on-other-columns-in-pandas-dataframe